Error connecting to the API: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded
setup

I have one standard Databricks, where Deployed Azure Databricks workspace in our own Virtual Network (VNet) is set to no

I have one more standard Databricks, where Deployed Azure Databricks workspace in our own Virtual Network (VNet) is set to Yes

I have one Azure translator where firewall is set to All networks


**Problem:- **
when I am calling azure translator api from azure Databricks1 then its working fine but getting error if I call the same azure translator api from 2nd Azure Databricks
**
error:-**
Error connecting to the API: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /translate?api-version=3.0&to=en (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f121f48e160>, 'Connection to api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))
(None, None)
Code
rule in nsg of subnet of dbk:-**
I think there is issue with NSG rule
may you also explain how to use azure translator if its access allowed only from selected network
